# Migrating user data from Community Builder

Tags: profile, joomla

We have a very large user database using Community Builder. After installing CiviCRM, it doesn't appear to be recognizing any of the data from Community Builder. Is there a migration tool or procedure to import that data into CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it and don't know whether it functions with current versions of CiviCRM, but there is (or was) a tool that seems related to what you are asking (although maybe just synchronizing going forward, not for existing contacts):
[Joomla 2 CiviCRM User Synchronization](https://civicrm.org/extensions/joomla-2-civicrm-user-synchronization)

> This plugin integrates the Joomla and/or Community Builder
>   registration process with CiviCRM.
>
> Newly created Joomla website users (from Joomla or Community Builder
>   frontend or backend) will be matched with existing CiviCRM contact(s)
>   based on their email address. If no matching CiviCRM contact is found,
>   a new one will be created and synchronized with the Joomla user. The
>   plugin can also be configured to attatch and assign a new CiviCRM
>   activity to the contact.

If that's not a good solution, you may be able to prepare or download a CSV file from Community Builder and do an [import to CiviCRM manually](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/).